# Kafka producer issue: UnknownTopicOrPartitionException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a question related to kafka issue we are facing. After running my kafka brokers for a longer time the producer starts sending the send request to wrong partition leader and the wrong leader rejects the message(which is acceptable). But the producer never updates its meta-data about the current correct leader. Any help? I am using kafka 0.9.0.1

Below is the error message in my log files:

> ERROR [ReplicaFetcherThread-18-2], Error for partition [topic1,2] to
>   broker
>   2:org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException:
>   This server does not host this topic-partition.
>   (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

Comment: Seems the exception is thrown by ReplicaFetcherThread which should be no related with the producer. Could you invoke kafka-topics script to check if  everything for the topic "topic1" is okay?